# Fit doesn't reach the peak in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I write a code, in python, in order to fit a gaussian distribution:

```
#NUMERICAL ESTIMATE OF PI

import numpy as np               #library for numerical calculations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  #library for plotting purposes
from scipy import constants      #needed for Physical and mathematical constants
from scipy.stats import norm     #needed for gaussian fit
  
#*******************************************************************************  


r = np.arange(1,10**5 +1)             #return evenly spaced values within a given interval.

pi = np.zeros(len(r))                 #a zero array of given len  

N = np.zeros(len(r))                  #a zero array of given len


  
circle_points = 0                     #number of points inside circle

square_points = 0                     #number of points outside circle
  
#*******************************************************************************

for i in range(len(r)):                      #for cycle over expected period
  
    rand_x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1)        #values randomly generated from a 
                                             #uniform distribution over (-1, 1)

    rand_y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1)        #values randomly generated from a 
                                             #uniform distribution over (-1, 1)
  
    origin_dist = rand_x**2 + rand_y**2      #distance between (x, y) from the origin
  
    
    if origin_dist <= 1:                     #If loop for hecking if (x, y) lies 
                                             #inside the circle
        circle_points += 1
  
    square_points += 1                       #or outside the circle
  
    pi[i] = (4* circle_points/ square_points) - constants.pi  #estimating value of pi 
                                                              #minus true value 

    N[i] = i                                                  #number of generated couples

     
#*******************************************************************************

plt.figure()                                                             #a unique identifier for the figure
plt.scatter(N,pi,marker=".")                                             #a scatter plot of y vs x
plt.grid()                                                               #configure the grid lines
plt.xlabel('Number of generated couples')                                #set the label for the x-axis
plt.ylabel('Pi - True Pi')                                               #set the label for the y-axis 
plt.ylim([-0.05, 0.05])                                                  #Get or set the y-limits of the current axes
plt.title("Plot of Pi - Tru Pi vs. Number of generated couples")         #set a title for the scatter plot
plt.show()                                                               #display all open figures

#*******************************************************************************

data = pi+constants.pi                                            #list of data   

_, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, 600, density=True)                    #sintex to create a histogram from a dataset x with n bins 
                                                                  #and store an array specifying the bin ranges in the variable bins.      

mu, sigma = norm.fit(data)                                        #get the mean and standard deviation of data

best_fit_line = norm.pdf(bins, mu, sigma)                         #get a line of best fit for the data

print("\n")
print("The mean of the distribution is ", mu, "The sigma of the distribution is", sigma, "\n")

#*******************************************************************************

plt.plot(bins, best_fit_line)                                     #plot y versus x as lines and/or markers
plt.hist(data, bins, ec="black", density=True)                    #compute and draw the histogram of x with n bins
plt.grid()                                                        #configure the grid lines
plt.xlabel('Bins',fontweight='bold')                              #set the label for the x-axis
plt.ylabel('Pi - true Pi',fontweight='bold')                      #set the label for the y-axis 
plt.xlim([3, 3.3])                                                #set the x-limits of the current axes
plt.title("Histogram for pi - True pi vs. bins")                  #set a title for the scatter plot
plt.show()                                                        #display all open figures

#*******************************************************************************
```

As you can see from the output:

[image: Output of the code]

the fit is not property correct... why?

I tryed some solution:

1. change density from True to False, bad solution;
2. change the number of bins, other bad solution.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: One point: you have `#distance between (x, y) from the origin` but the formula calculates the square of the distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I and my colleague re-write the code and this time works perfectly:

```
#NUMERICAL ESTIMATE OF PI

import numpy as np               #library for numerical calculations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  #library for plotting purposes
from scipy.stats import norm     #needed for gaussian fit
  
M = 10**6                               #number of times we calculate pi

N = 100                                 #number of point generated, statistics: 100, 1000 a 5000

mean_pi=[]                              #empy list

for i in range(M):                      #for loops over the period

    x=np.random.uniform(-1,1,N)         #array of the given shape d and populate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [-1,1)
    y=np.random.uniform(-1,1,N)         #array of the given shape d and populate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [-1,1)

    x_sel=x[(x**2+y**2)<=1]             #selection of x point
    y_sel=y[(x**2+y**2)<=1]             #selection of y point

    mean_pi+=[4*len(x_sel)/len(x)]      #list of pi's mean value

    
_,bins,_=plt.hist(mean_pi,bins=int(np.sqrt(N)),density=True)      #sintex to create a histogram from a dataset x with n bins 
                                                                  #and store an array specifying the bin ranges in the variable bins. 

mu, sigma = norm.fit(mean_pi)                                     #get the mean and standard deviation of data

k = sigma*np.sqrt(N)                                              #k parameters

best_fit_line = norm.pdf(bins, mu, sigma)                         #get a line of best fit for the data

print("Results for statistics N:", N, ". The mean of the distribution is: ", mu, ". The standard deviation is:", sigma, ". The k parameters is:", k ,". \n")


plt.plot(bins, best_fit_line)                                         #plot y versus x as lines and/or markers
plt.grid()                                                            #configure the grid lines
plt.xlabel('Bins',fontweight='bold')                                  #set the label for the x-axis
plt.ylabel('Pi',fontweight='bold')                                    #set the label for the y-axis 
plt.title("Histogram for Pi vs. bins with statistics egual to 100")   #set a title for the scatter plot
plt.show()                                                            #display all open figures

print("\n")


M = 10**6                               #number of times we calculate pi

N = 1000                                 #number of point generated, statistics: 100, 1000 a 5000

mean_pi=[]                              #empy list

for i in range(M):                      #for loops over the period

    x=np.random.uniform(-1,1,N)         #array of the given shape d and populate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [-1,1)
    y=np.random.uniform(-1,1,N)         #array of the given shape d and populate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [-1,1)

    x_sel=x[(x**2+y**2)<=1]             #selection of x point
    y_sel=y[(x**2+y**2)<=1]             #selection of y point

    mean_pi+=[4*len(x_sel)/len(x)]      #list of pi's mean value

    
_,bins,_=plt.hist(mean_pi,bins=int(np.sqrt(N)),density=True)      #sintex to create a histogram from a dataset x with n bins 
                                                                  #and store an array specifying the bin ranges in the variable bins. 

mu, sigma = norm.fit(mean_pi)                                     #get the mean and standard deviation of data

k = sigma*np.sqrt(N)                                              #k parameters

best_fit_line = norm.pdf(bins, mu, sigma)                         #get a line of best fit for the data

print("Results for statistics N:", N, ". The mean of the distribution is: ", mu, ". The standard deviation is:", sigma, ". The k parameters is:", k ,". \n")


plt.plot(bins, best_fit_line)                                          #plot y versus x as lines and/or markers
plt.grid()                                                             #configure the grid lines
plt.xlabel('Bins',fontweight='bold')                                   #set the label for the x-axis
plt.ylabel('Pi',fontweight='bold')                                     #set the label for the y-axis 
plt.title("Histogram for Pi vs. bins with statistics egual to 1000")   #set a title for the scatter plot
plt.show()                                                             #display all open figures

print("\n")


M = 10**6                               #number of times we calculate pi

N = 5000                                 #number of point generated, statistics: 100, 1000 a 5000

mean_pi=[]                              #empy list

for i in range(M):                      #for loops over the period

    x=np.random.uniform(-1,1,N)         #array of the given shape d and populate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [-1,1)
    y=np.random.uniform(-1,1,N)         #array of the given shape d and populate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [-1,1)

    x_sel=x[(x**2+y**2)<=1]             #selection of x point
    y_sel=y[(x**2+y**2)<=1]             #selection of y point

    mean_pi+=[4*len(x_sel)/len(x)]      #list of pi's mean value

    
_,bins,_=plt.hist(mean_pi,bins=int(np.sqrt(N)),density=True)      #sintex to create a histogram from a dataset x with n bins 
                                                                  #and store an array specifying the bin ranges in the variable bins. 

mu, sigma = norm.fit(mean_pi)                                     #get the mean and standard deviation of data

k = sigma*np.sqrt(N)                                              #k parameters

best_fit_line = norm.pdf(bins, mu, sigma)                         #get a line of best fit for the data

print("Results for statistics N:", N, ". The mean of the distribution is: ", mu, ". The standard deviation is:", sigma, ". The k parameters is:", k ,". \n")


plt.plot(bins, best_fit_line)                                         #plot y versus x as lines and/or markers
plt.grid()                                                            #configure the grid lines
plt.xlabel('Bins',fontweight='bold')                                  #set the label for the x-axis
plt.ylabel('Pi',fontweight='bold')                                    #set the label for the y-axis 
plt.title("Histogram for Pi vs. bins with statistics egual to 5000")  #set a title for the scatter plot
plt.show()                                                            #display all open figures
```

The output are:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: For future visitors, will you explain in words what you did differently in this version?

Comment: I'm honest, we didn't understand the mistake. By rewriting the code from scratch we saw that everything was going the right way.

Answer (score 0):

```
origin_dist = rand_x**2 + rand_y**2      #distance between (x, y) from the origin
```

This is actually the square of the distance. If that still works for your purposes, that is fine, but you should accurately understand what you are actually calculating

```
square_points += 1                       #or outside the circle
```

You always increment `square_points` even for points that are inside the circle. Is this really what you want?

The difference between these actual calculations and what you state in the comments you are calculating might explain the difference between your graphs and what you want instead.

Comment: I want to increment ```square_points``` only if the point is outside the circle.

Comment: @J.Snowden Then you should fix your code.

Comment: Sorry, i made confusion. The ```square_points``` are the point into the square and is egual to the total number of points, so it is correct.

My problem is in the fit of the gaussian distribution, how you can see the fit is no correct.

Comment: @J.Snowden I can see that the fit isn't what you think it should be. What do you think it should be instead and why?

Comment: @J.Snowden As a side note, you can do `square_points = len(r)` or `square_points = 10**5+1` and remove `square_points += 1`. You can also reuse this everywhere it is needed instead of calculating `len(r)` multiple times.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this advice. What about the fit?

Comment: @J.Snowden What do you think it should be instead? And why?

Comment: I think the fit should be proportional to the height of the central peak and also have a smaller standard deviation given the number of samples generated.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. I think you should double check your assumptions. For example, how are you judge the "smallness" of the stddev? I think you shouldn't judge it in absolute terms. Instead, compare the stddev to the mean. The stddev is 0.4%. Now you can judge whether this is "small" or not.

Comment: 0.4% is too much, i need 0.001%. Ok, i can increase the number of points but the fit looks bad.

Comment: @J.Snowden I don't see anything obviously wrong here, as I said earlier. My next suggestion is to find a way to verify the calculation. For example, you could write the data out to a file and then use Excel to calculate the stddev and mean. You should also double check the scale on the axes are meaningful for both the pdf historgram and the normal distribution. These are just a couple of things that come to mind to check. They might not be problems and there are probably others to check as well.

Comment: In excel the value of mean and std are identical but the fit looks perfect...